# Add a filled rectangle to text in a table cell using only CSS

Tags: css

I have html code that defines a table, like this:

```html
<table>
  <th>
     <td style="width:200px">
        col1
     </td>
  </th>
  <tr>
     <td id="a1">
        text1
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I like to draw a rectangle right of "text1", i.e. into the cell #a1, with a custom width (e.g. 40px) and a fixed offset (e.g. 100px) from the left side of the cell, using only CSS, so that it appears like this:

```
text1  XXXX
```

(XXXX is meant to be the filled rectangle)

I have no control over the html, i.e. I cannot change it, so please don't suggest that. No JS, either.

It is important that the css does not alter the appearance and positioning of the text.

Is that doable with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `::after` pseudo-element. `outline` is added to show the 100px offset; clearly, it's not required.

```css
#a1 {
  outline: red 1px solid
}

#a1::after {
  content: '\a0';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  background: #000;
  transform: translateX(50px)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:200px">
      col1
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="a1">
      text1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a background:

```css
#a1 {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(red, red) 
   left 100px top 50% 
   /
   40px 10px  /*width height (use 100% instead of 10px for full height)*/
   no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:200px">
      col1
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="a1">
      text1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```